# Sort Rows from Pandas DataFrame Inplace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to sort only select rows in a DataFrame. Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_set)
df.loc[df.category == 'Filter_Category'] = df.loc[df.category == 'Filter_Category'].sort_values(by=['Field_Name'], inplace=True)
```

This resulted in "None" in the updated section. Then I tried this:

```
    df2 = df.loc[df.category == 'Filter_Category'].copy()
    df2.sort_values(by=['Field_Name'], inplace=True)
    df.update(df2)
```

This updated seemed to update rows, but did not maintain the new order. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add `values`, since `pandas` will match the index as well, so make the `sort_values` dose not change original value

```
df.loc[df.category == 'Filter_Category'] = \
df.loc[df.category == 'Filter_Category'].sort_values(by=['Field_Name']).tolist().values
```

Comment: Thanks! When I do that I get this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'